# L5 Form Model Binding with multiple Parameter

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

How to make Form::model with multiple parameter?
i have example route like this.
www.domain.com/product/2/product-attributes/3/edit
in normal form i can do it like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('product.{product}.product-attributes.update', [$product->id, $product-attribute->id ]) }}"> </form>
```

but if im trying to use laravelcolective/html Form::model() like this:

```
Form::model($productattributes, array('method' => 'POST', array('route' => array('product.{product}.product-attributes.update', [$product->id, $product-attribute->id ])))
```

i get an error array to string conversion...

**==== UPDATE ==============**

My Routes:

```
Route::resource('backend/product', 'Backend\ProductController');
Route::resource('backend/product/{product}/product-attributes', 'Backend\ProductAttributesController',['except' => ['index']]);
```

===== UPDATE 2 =========================

already solved but i will prove my route not wrong
php artisan route:list
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

im just trying.. if normal route use array to pass multiple parameter. i guess Form::model dont need to use array just separate with ,

Normal Route ::

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('product.{product}.product-attributes.update', [$product->id, $product-attribute->id ]) }}"> </form>
```

Form Model ::

```
Form::model($productattributes, array('method' => 'POST', array('route' => array('product.{product}.product-attributes.update', $product->id, $product-attribute->id)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I've never seen a route name with curly braces in it like yours:

`product.{product}.product-attributes.update`

So unsure what purpose that serves? Maybe you can share your route with us?

For me I'd do it like this...

Say you have a route:

```
Route::get('product/{product_id}/product-attributes/{product_atrribute_id}/edit',[
    'as'   => 'product.product-attributes.update',
    'uses' => 'ProductController@updateProduct',

]);
```

Then you can call your route method like this:

```
route('product.product-attributes.update', 
    ['product_id' => product->id, 'product_atrribute_id' => $product-attribute->id ]
)
```

The difference here (between the way you call the method and I have) is that I've specified the array keys that match the keys in the url.

As for opening the form I think you'd do it link this:

(Please note I've made some assumptions as you haven't shared much of your code)

```
Form::model( 
    // pass it the product so the product id can be accessed directly 
    // and the attributes id can be accessed through relationship method
    $product, 
    [
        'method' => 'POST', [
            'route' => [
                'product.product-attributes.update', [
                    'product_id' => $product->id, 
                    'product_attributes_id' => $product->attribute->id
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
)
```

Please note the mistake in your code: `product->id` should be: `$product->id`

Comment: it's just typo :x, I already update my routes.. i'm using Route::resource. I dont have problem on normal form except when I using Laravelcollective HTML/Form : Form::model

Comment: If you're using a route resource, run `artisan route:list` to get the correct name of your route, I'm pretty sure it's not `product.{product}.product-attributes.update`

Comment: solved but if you ask of my route:list to prove my route like that you can see my update @haakym

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise you could have a route name with {} in it, or at least that's how it would be generated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be using a 'nested resource' (adjust naming as needed)

```
Route::resource('backend/product.attributes', 'Backend\ProductAttributesController',['except' => ['index']]);
```

Route (Show):

```
backend/product/{product}/attributes/{attributes}
```

[Laravel Docs - Nested Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: i have no problem with the route... i just have problem with the Form::model for form model binding